# Arc2D.Double contains(double x, double y) method not working

Tags: java, user-interface, jpanel, contains, geometric-arc

Background: A little background info, this is taking place on JPanel (PiePanel) thats inside a JPanel on a JFrame. On PiePanel, i have added a Component  that draws objects from class Pie that extends Arc2D.Double and creates Arcs in PIE form. Essentially I'm making pie chart.

I made constants in Pie class for making the arc as: x = 20, y = 20, w = 240, h = 240

```
public TestComponent()  {
    setPreferredSize(new Dimension(280,270));
    pies = new ArrayList<PieChartSlice>();
    Pie a = new Pie(0, 120, Color.black);
    pies.add(a);
    System.out.println(a.contains(150.0,130.0));
    }
```

Since the dimensions are 280 by 270, and i start each pies bounded box with x,y = 20 and h,w = 240, the middle of the piechart should be (140,140). Since the Pie 'a'  is 120 degrees, coordinates 150,130 should definitely be in Pie a, but it returns false!!

It also seems that a.toString() gives  PieChartSlice@0

Comment: Maybe you can show the Pie class  code?

Comment: Can you post an [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org) that demonstrates the problem using only the `Arc2D.Double` class?

Comment: A buddy of mine showed me how much an idiot i am, shows over folks ;)

Comment: @user: could you post the solution in case anyone runs into a similar problem?

Answer (score 0):

I just had this problem and while I can't definitively provide the answer the OP's problem without seeing their code, I did figure out a solution to my identical problem (a point clearly inside the arc is not being "seen".)

When calling the constructor

```
Arc2D.Double(double x, double y, double w, double h, double start, double extent,
             int type)
```

use `Arc2D.PIE` for `int type`. The other two types didn't work for me.